# Multiple input streams into a program from a file of unknown length

Tags: bash, unix, pipe, bioinformatics

I'm trying to process a file, BigFile as follows:

```
TypeA
TypeB
TypeA
TypeB
...
```

Where TypeA and TypeB represent lines that are going to be split into two files, FileA and FileB, respectively. Preferably, I want to refer to FileA and FileB as streams, because I view them more similarly to a stream such as /dev/stdin.

My problem is that BigFile gets lines added to it as time proceeds. So, I try to do the following:

```
my_program -1 streamA -2 streamB
```

But I'm not sure which programs to use / order of syntax to make this possible. Here, -1 and -2 just signify that -1 is the first "file" and -2 is the second "file".

What I've done so far is as follows:

```
mkfifo streamA streamB
```

I then have been running a loop which basically does:

```
for f in *.ext;

  read #this is just used to test changes when I press enter

  do egrep 'TypeA_Criteria' $f >> streamA
  do egrep 'TypeB_Criteria' $f >> streamB
done
```

I also tried process substitution as suggested below with:

```
bowtie2 -x definedSizeGenomeFile -1 <(tail -f fileA) -2 <(tail -f fileB)
```

And I also tried to use `&` at the end so that it doesn't complete tasks one after the other, but run in parallel. However, I am seeing now output from my program.

To rephrase the question;

How can I run

```
  my_prog -1 <(tail -f fileA) -2 <(tail -f fileB)
```

as if they are both similar to /dev/stdin, where the program will not stop reading until it gets to the end of stream character? I wrote another script to facilitate killing the instance when it got to a certain line, but at this point I just want these things to run in parallel.

Thanks a lot! Please indicate anywhere requiring more clarification.

Comment: Can you maybe add a timeout to the `tail -f`, so it becomes `tail -f fileA | while read -t 20 xxx; do echo "$xxx"; done`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
my_program -1 <(grep -h 'TypeA_Criteria' *.ext) -2 <(grep -h 'TypeB_Criteria' *.ext)
```

Comment: The problem is that files will continue to be added into the directory, potentially after the first lot of *.ext is processed.

Comment: you can put any code you want into the process substitution. It could be a loop that repeatedly looks for new files. You can call another script that does this.

Comment: So it could be `<(some_script 'TypeA_Criteria')` and `some_script` does what you want to find new files and process them.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I use `<(tail -f myFile)`, which is kind of the point: my files are growing with time and so the EOF/EOT character can't be read until I kill the `tail` process

Comment: I think you may have to use `<(tail -f myfile&)`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that (sorry I should have mentioned that, which I did in the updated question), but it seems nothing is being outputted. Its kind of vague because I'm not mentioning the program, which is `bowtie`, a genome alignment program for bioinformatics

Comment: I think that would work if I could manipulate it to output from the background whenever a line was added to the file

Comment: How does `my_prog` read from its input files? Does it use non-blocking reads and/or `select`? If it tries to read either file until EOF, it obviously can't work with `tail -f` supplying the input, since there's no EOF.